# How do you keep user.config settings across different assembly versions in .net?

Tags: .net, settings, assemblyversions

Basically the problem is that each time the assembly version changes (i.e. the user installs a new version of the application) all their settings are reset the the defaults (or more accurately a new user.config file is created in a folder with a different version number as the name)

How can I keep the same settings when upgrading versions, since using ini files or the registry seem to be discouraged?

When we used Clickonce it seemed to be able to handle this, so it seems like it should be able to be done, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534119/semi-editable-files-eg-config-files-and-version-control-best-practices/534170)?

Comment: No, that's referring to default to not checking a file into version control (or so I gathered)  This is in regards to (Windows) user specific settings for an end user

Comment: Just the question I needed, thanks :)

Comment: I've posted a possible solution in the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47921377/3223783 Hope that helps!

Comment: I've posted a possible solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47921377/3223783). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 270, accepted):

ApplicationSettingsBase has a [method called Upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade.aspx) which migrates all settings from the previous version.

In order to run the merge whenever you publish a new version of your application you can define a boolean flag in your settings file that defaults to true. Name it **UpgradeRequired** or something similar.

Then, at application start you check to see if the flag is set and if it is, call the [Upgrade method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade.aspx), set the flag to false and save your configuration.

```
if (Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired)
{
    Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired = false;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Read more about the Upgrade method at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade.aspx). The [GetPreviousVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.getpreviousversion.aspx) might also be worth a look if you need to do some custom merging.

Comment: A little question, what constitutes a new version? Any part of the 4 part number? I use ClickOnce so is that a different animal?

Comment: What type of setting should **UpgradeRequired** be? `appSettings`, `userSettings`, or `applicationSettings`? As a User setting on Settings.Settings, once the first time it's changed to false it will never be true again. A new version won't reset a that **UpgradeRequired** back to True.

Comment: @dialex It must be a User setting. Settings of type Application are read-only. New version numbers do cause settings to reset because settings are stored in a version-specific path.

Comment: Dead links all around

Comment: You can see pretty much the same answer here in the 8th question:- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rprabhu/archive/2005/06/29/433979.aspx

Comment: Instead of / in addition to `UpgradeRequired`, I would store the App's version as a Setting.  That allows you to perform custom upgrade conversions (i.e., of an invalid value / valid value to other than -the latest version's default / -same value).  You can have code that converts each applicable version needing conversion to the next lowest version that requires it and daisy chain the code together thereby: a) reducing complexity of the latest version's conversion code and b) allowing for potential retiring of old conversion code.

Comment: Why not just skip the extra property dance and call `Settings.Default.Upgrade()` every time the application starts?  Any downside?

Comment: I think I answered my own question.  If a previous version of the settings file exists, it will copy its values into the newest version every time the app starts up, probably not what you want!

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that this isn't just default behavior; if the application's settings are null on start and it finds a previous bunch of settings, it loads them.

Answer (score 16):

The next short solution works for me when we need to upgrade only once per version. It does *not* required additional settings like `UpgradeRequired`:

```cs
if (!ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal).HasFile)
    Settings.Default.Upgrade();
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work during debug.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been awhile...
In a winforms app, just call `My.Settings.Upgrade()` before you load them. This will get the latest settings, whether the current version or a previous version.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my research in case anyone else is having a hard time with migrating settings that have been changed/removed. Basic problem is that `GetPreviousVersion()` does not work if you have renamed or removed the setting in the new version of your application. So you need to keep the setting in your `Settings` class, but add a few attributes/artifacts to it so that you don't inadvertently use it in the code elsewhere, making it obsolete. A sample obsolete setting would look like this in VB.NET (can easily be translated to C#):

```
<UserScopedSetting(),
DebuggerNonUserCode(),
DefaultSettingValue(""),
Obsolete("Do not use this property for any purpose. Use YOUR_NEW_SETTING_NAME instead."),
NoSettingsVersionUpgrade()>
Public Property OldSettingName() As String
  Get
    Throw New NotSupportedException("This property is obsolete")
  End Get
  Set
    Throw New NotSupportedException("This property is obsolete")
  End Set
End Property
```

Make sure you add this property to the same namespace/class that has your application settings. In VB.NET, this class is named `MySettings` and is available in `My` namespace. You can use partial class functionality to prevent your obsolete settings from mixing up with your current settings.

Full credit to jsharrison for posting an [excellent article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247333/Renaming-User-Settings-properties-between-software) about this issue. You can read more details about it there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation on the solutions presented here that encapsulates the upgrade logic into an abstract class that settings classes can derive from.

Some proposed solutions use a DefaultSettingsValue attribute to specify a value that indicates when previous settings were not loaded. My preference is to simply use a type whose default value indicates this. As a bonus, a DateTime? is helpful debugging information.

```
public abstract class UserSettingsBase : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    public UserSettingsBase() : base()
    {
        // Accessing a property attempts to load the settings for this assembly version
        // If LastSaved has no value (default) an upgrade might be needed
        if (LastSaved == null)
        {
            Upgrade();
        }
    }

    [UserScopedSetting]
    public DateTime? LastSaved
    {
        get { return (DateTime?)this[nameof(LastSaved)]; }
        private set { this[nameof(LastSaved)] = value; }
    }

    public override void Save()
    {
        LastSaved = DateTime.Now;
        base.Save();
    }
}
```

Derive from UserSettingsBase:

```
public class MySettings : UserSettingsBase
{
    [UserScopedSetting]
    public string SomeSetting
    {
        get { return (string)this[nameof(SomeSetting)]; }
        set { this[nameof(SomeSetting)] = value; }
    }

    public MySettings() : base() { }
}
```

And use it:

```
// Existing settings are loaded and upgraded if needed
MySettings settings = new MySettings();
...
settings.SomeSetting = "SomeValue";
...
settings.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your changes to user.settings are done programmatically, how about maintaining a copy of (just) the modifications to user.settings in a separate file, e.g. user.customized.settings?

You probably still want to maintain and load the modified settings in user.settings as well.  But this way when you install a newer version of your application with its newer version of user.settings you can ask the user if they want to continue to use their modified settings by copying them back into the new user.settings.  You could import them wholesale, or get fancier and ask the user to confirm which settings they want to continue to use.

*EDIT: I read too quickly over the "more accurately" part about assembly versions causing a new user.settings to be installed into a new version-specific directory.  Thus, the idea above probably doesn't help you, but may provide some food for thought.*

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handled it:

```
public virtual void LoadSettings(ServiceFileFormBaseSettings settings = null, bool resetSettingsToDefaults = false)
{
    if (settings == null)
            return;

    if (resetSettingsToDefaults)
        settings.Reset();
    else
    {
        settings.Reload();

        if (settings.IsDefault)
            settings.Upgrade();
    }

    this.Size = settings.FormSize;
```

}

and in the settings class, I defined the IsDefault property:

```
// SaveSettings always sets this to be FALSE.
// This will have the default value TRUE when first deployed, or immediately after an upgrade.
// When the settings exist, this is false.
//
[UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[DefaultSettingValueAttribute("true")]
public virtual bool IsDefault
{
    get { return (bool)this["IsDefault"]; }
    set { this["IsDefault"] = value; }
}
```

In the SaveSettings, I set IsDefault to false:

```
public virtual void SaveSettings(ServiceFileFormBaseSettings settings = null)
{
    if (settings == null) // ignore calls from this base form, if any
        return;

    settings.IsDefault = false;
    settings.FormSize = this.Size;
    settings.Save();
}
```