# Application settings cannot be upgraded

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

My C# application uses the default C# settings mechanism. The problem here is, that everytime I change my application's version number, all settings are gone and reset to their defaults.

Thus I implemented [the upgrade mechanism described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47921377/619774).

**Problem 1:**

The weird thing is, that this seems to have no effect. After the upgrade code is executed, all settings still have their default values and none of the old values have been loaded.

Does the upgrade mechanism not work?

**Problem 2:**

Also after saving the settings, a new settings folder is created in AppData/Local (the name differs in the URI part). So after a couple of versions there are dozens of these folders lurking around, which does not feel right.

Is it normal behavior that an application creates new settings folders for each version?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Yes: Pooblem 1: in which cases does the upgrade mechanism not work? Problem 2: Is it normal behavior that an application creates new settings folders for each version?