# .Net core single file build is generating multiple setting folders with different hashes for each assemblyversion

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, .net-core-publishsinglefile

im using .Net Core 3.1 and WPF for my project and today i was playing a little bit with the settings.All worked fine. I can save values and i can access this values after restart.

After that im increased my assembly value from 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.0.1 and the settings are gone... I searched many hours to fix this issue but i did not found any solution.

[Keep user's settings after altering assembly/file version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924183/keep-users-settings-after-altering-assembly-file-version/47921377#47921377)

This was a pretty nice solution but this is not working for me. WHY?

Easy to say after every **single file build** and access to any Setting.Default values my appilcation generates a new setting folder with an new hash.

So i have multiple folders with each one user.config. Without the single file build it works fine. The new assembly version gets generated in the latest folder and i can update ist like the solution above.

[image]

Currently i need so setup my app again on eveery new assembly version :/
Someone had the same issue and can help me? Why is my application creating multiple settings folder for each assemblyversion?

1. .Net Core 3.1
2. Visual Studio 2022 (17.2.2)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Upgrade method for migrating settings from previous versions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#System_Configuration_ApplicationSettingsBase_Upgrade

It notifies all of the corresponding settings providers of the existence of the upgraded application through a call to their IApplicationSettingsProvider.Upgrade method.

You can override the default behavior of Upgrade to implement custom upgrading or merging behavior. Use the GetPreviousVersion method to retrieve individual values for a setting for the previous version of the application.

Comment: No i tried this but the upgrade methode only works if the different assembly versions in the same folder. But the single file publishing creates multiple folders with each on assembly.

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2022 (17.3.2) and .NetCore 3.1 for single file replication, but I am not having your problem.  You can take a look at this lin'k https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634188/Upgrading-Settings-files-when-changing-application, I hope it can help you.