# Desktop Bridge - Upgrade Settings not working

Tags: merge, settings, upgrade, desktop-bridge

I am trying to upgrade the user settings if my app gets updated. I am storing settings ins
 Properties.Settings.Default. As suggested in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477576/how-to-persist-changes-in-a-settings-config-file-across-a-file-version-change) a way to merge settings between version is to can create a bool setting UpgradeRequired and do the following.

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired)
{
Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired = false;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
 }
```

I tried to make a minimum example with this code in a desktop bridge app without any success. Does this method not work for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately this does not currently work in desktop bridge apps. This is a known bug that the team is aware off.

As a possible workaround you could move to the new localsettings API in your desktop bridge app:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalSettings

Comment: What's the status of this bug now? Is there any detailed explanation and/or example of how to implement the workaround you've linked above?