# How to reload old settings when you update program?

Tags: c#, settings

I have settings saved for the user, but after they update it removes them.

I did some Googling and found this code but it keeps giving me errors on `.UpdateRequired` that it doesnt exist.

Am I missing an assembly?

```
if (Settings.Default.UpdateRequired)
            {
                Settings.Default.Update();
                Settings.Default.UpdateRequired = false;
            }
```

Comment: Did you define the boolean flag UpgradeRequired in you settings file?  Here is a similar article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534261/how-do-you-keep-user-config-settings-across-different-assembly-versions-in-net/534335#534335.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @Rob4md What settings file? Where is it located sorry?

Comment: How is the application updated, what mechanism are you using?

Comment: @Maarten Microsofts setup deployment. I think thats what its called

Comment: @Edwin ClickOnce deployment?

Comment: @Maarten Its in visual studio professional. Its called Visual Studio Installer or a Setup Project