# How to remove previous user settings after settings upgrade?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

After doing a:

```
MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
```

How can I remove any previous setting files? The problem I'm having is I have a function where the user can reset his/her own data using:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reset();
```

However on the next start of the application, since the old user settings are still there it will be upgraded again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to do this other than doing it manually yourself.
So after a successful upgrade, you can remove the old version manually using file system methods.

Answer (score 0):

[How do you keep user.config settings across different assembly versions in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534261/how-do-you-keep-user-config-settings-across-different-assembly-versions-in-net/534335#534335)
seems to be what you are looking for.

So use Upgrade, UpgradeRequired=true or false, and Save : it would be quite long to explain all cases, but it is in fact quite easy to figure out what to do.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue though, I'm already doing something similar in my application. The issue is when the _current_ settings are removed via Reset(), the previous settings will be upgraded again as there will be no record of Upgrade = false anymore. How can I totally remove the actual previous version setting files?