# Do not overwrite settings.settings file with clickonce

Tags: c#, clickonce, app-config

At first I had some userdefined settings stored in my app.config file, under appSettings.
These are properties the user can change during runtime.
The first problem I've got is when I deploy my application with ClickOnce it overwrites the app.config file and the user has lost his personal settings.

Then I moved the properties to the settings.settings file (= usersettings section in app.config) as I found on the internet that this section doesn't get overwritten when deploying with ClickOnce. Nah, it does..
Settings.Settings properties are:

- Build action = content
- Copy to = Do not copy

So how can I accomplish that my user's personal settings are not overwritten, either in the app.config file or the settings.settings file. Or is there another way and am I doing it wrong?

Thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method copies the settings from the previous installation when deploying a new version of the application with ClickOnce. 
So any user defined settings that the user made will be copied and thus available after the update. I tested this and it works for me.

```
public static void UpgradeUserSettings()
{
  if (Settings.Default.upgradeRequired)
  {
    Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Settings.Default.upgradeRequired = false;
    Settings.Default.Save();
  }
}
```

[ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade Method MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade.aspx)

[other question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534261/how-do-you-keep-user-config-settings-across-different-assembly-versions-in-net)

Comment: where should I embed this code in my application,actually I put this code in Program.cs before running the application and didn't worked ?!!

Comment: I'm kind of in the same place @franchescototti. This looks like an elegant solution, but I've no idea where to put it...