# use settings.default.upgrade to keep setting when update to new version clickonce

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I used following code that mention on this post 
[Do not overwrite settings.settings file with clickonce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400943/do-not-overwrite-settings-settings-file-with-clickonce?rq=1)
but it is not working for my connection string that stored in setting with application scope, I am in doubt that this method work for user scope only or both application and user scope ?

```
if (Settings.Default.upgradeRequired)
  {
    Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Settings.Default.upgradeRequired = false;
    Settings.Default.Save();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with that by adding one more setting named "userconnection" Scope:User then
every time that user must set its connection string then this  "userconnection" updated, Then in main point of my application check if userconnection(User Scope)!=ConnectionString(Applicaiton Scope) then try to change application ConnectionString to user customized one which was stored in userconnection properties.