# How to take a backup of existing config files?

Tags: .net, windows-installer, setup-deployment

Here is my problem, I need to take a backup of existing config files in a folder while installing my product.msi setup.  I tried using the (Using Custom Actions) `Installer Class` it works but not in a right direction.

**It takes the backup only after the entire installation completes. ie.,After install I used to get 3 config files, those 3 are taken as a backup in the folder.**

My installation class:

```
[System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
        public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install(stateSaver);
        }        

        [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
        public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Commit(savedState);

            string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); 
            String folderPath = directory + "\\Myproduct Before " + version;
            string[] newPath = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.config");
            int newPathCounter = newPath.Count();
            if (newPathCounter != 0)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < newPath.Count(); i++)
                {
                    string source = newPath[i];
                    string destination = source.Replace(directory, folderPath);
                    File.Copy(source, destination, true);
                }                
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No files to copy");
            }
        }

        [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
        public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Rollback(savedState);
        }

        [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
        public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Uninstall(savedState);
        }
```

I also tried giving this code in `OnBeforeInstall` but the same thing happens.  Please advice on this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are not providing correct path to config files.

Here are the possible ways to manage application configurations:

The config files are installed to application directory in program files but they are copied to app data folder as soon as any change is made to config file at run time.

You may upgrade newly installed application from existing configuration if needed
[How do you keep user.config settings across different assembly versions in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534261/how-do-you-keep-user-config-settings-across-different-assembly-versions-in-net)

Every time a new version of an application is installed, it creates a new folder under %AppData\Local\%\ and put new configuration files there. The existing files stay in the older folder which can be copied any time but you will need to find the correct path or just copy the complete folder which would always be named after your application name.