# How to use properly app.config?

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config

Currently i have created in my library an app.config file builted like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
<appSettings>
  <add key ="DATE" value="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
  <add key ="TIME" value="HH:mm|HH:mm:ss"/>
  <add key ="DURATION" value="ss|mm:ss|hh:mm:ss|hhmmss"/>
  <add key ="LAT_LONG" value="dd.ddddd[N,S]dd.ddddd[E,W]|[-]dd.ddddd°,[-]dd.ddddd°|[-]ddmmss.ssss, [-]dddmmss.ssss "/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I need my user to modify this settings by adding and/or removing format and even adding new settings to the file. I'm using `ConfigurationManager` to do that.

Now i have a doubt that this will actually work when this app will be deployed, cause, if i understand what i read in my previous research, `appSettings` cannot be modified at runtime. Do i have to use `userSettings`? and in that case can i add them directly in this `app.Config` file? how exactly work `userSettings`? Can i interact with them with the `ConfigurationManager`?

EDIT: ok i understand that i've asked a lot of stuff, so let's make the thing simple. Can i add userSettings node to my app.Config ? If yes, do my application work actually on them?

Comment: It will be too broad and off-topic o write a tutorial on this key part of NET. You can find a well known tutorial here [Cracking the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19675/Cracking-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration#duplicate=0)

Comment: [User Settings in WPF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patrickdanino/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf/)

Comment: @stuartd yeah ok, but are settings and app.config the same thing? i don't think so

Comment: @Steve can i work on user.Config using Configuration manager?

Comment: Not exactly the same, no, but linked.

Comment: Usually you work with these settings using the `yourtype.Settings.Default.NameOfTheConfiguration`

Comment: What you ask is covered in tutorial, MSDN and a lot of articles. There are a *lot* of them. If you go to your project's properties, you'll even find a `Settings` section.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to setup a user personalized configuration, you can follow the easy path prepared for us (the developers) from MS.

In this case you simply define your initial settings with the Properties menu of your project and then choosing Settings.

Here you can define two kind of settings. The Application settings (valid for all users on that machine and not easily modifiable from code) and the User Settings. These last ones are kept separated user by user and written somewhere in some obsure folder on the client machine inside the user folder hierarchy.

These settings can be changed and saved at runtime using the Settings class.
So suppose you have added a setting like DateFormat of type string and scope User in the Settings configuration of your project.

Now you can retrieve it with

```
string format = Settings.Default.DateFormat;
....
format = "dd/MM/yy";
Settings.Default.DateFormat = format;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

This is just the basic to let you start. You should also look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534261/how-do-you-keep-user-config-settings-across-different-assembly-versions-in-net/534335#534335) to handle the situation when you need to upgrade the information stored in the user settings file

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you consider to approach this a little differently. i.e instead of using appconfig, why not use a text file or database(may be too much overhead for this use case) to store user specific settings. AppConfig is for application specific stuff and it is probably a good idea to separate user concerns out of there anyways. Store user settings as json object in a text file and serialize it directly to your UserSettings object.

However, take a look at [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) to deal with AppSettings, Serializing/DeSerializing settings to your POCO objects. Here's [an example](http://docs.servicestack.net/appsettings#appsettings-are-writable) of how to use the api for AppSettings.

But again, instead of using AppSettings, you can read/write from the text file and serialize to your object of choice, still using the same apis.